# apache2 configtest failed with output "No MPM loaded."

Tags: 14.04, networking, apache2

```
root@tasnim:/home/tara# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
```

Output of config test was:

```
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Using

```
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
service apache2 restart
```

I got:

```
root@tasnim:/home/tara# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                  [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
```

Output of config test was:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 156 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Then i open the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file and got that:

```
//access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied //this is line 156
</Directory>
```

Using

```
 apt-cache policy apache2
```

i got:

```
root@tasnim:/home/tara# apt-cache policy apache2
apache2:
Installed: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4
Candidate: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4
Version table:
*** 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.4 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.4.7-1ubuntu4 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Using

```
 a2query -v
```

i got:

```
root@tasnim:/home/tara# a2query -v
2.4.7
```

Comment: Please don't use HTML to format. See http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Which version of Apache are you using? How did you install it? Add the output of `apt-cache policy apache2` and `a2query -v`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem Like :

```
Starting web server apache2 
* The apache2 configtest failed. 
Output of config test was: apache2: 
Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_itk.load: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mpm_itk.so into server: 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mpm_itk.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory Action 'configtest' failed. 
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I try this : `apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk` so I resolve my problem, reinstall the files which is missing so i can recover.

Thanks I hop you guys can get solution.

Comment: This will enable the prefork mpm

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sudo a2enmod auth_basic authn_core authn_file authz_core authz_host authz_user access_compat
> ```

enable modules to start the server

Taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246466/165104) by [A.B.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/107084/a-b) to [this question on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246426/trying-to-restart-apache-using-vagrant-the-apache2-configtest-failed)